# How to migrate a MySQL DB to SAP HANA

Tags: mysql, database-migration, hana

How do I move my existing Mysql Database into SAP HANA **without rewriting the database**
Is there a simple way or a technique i can do the same ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check following SAP resource https://www.sap.com/products/hana/implementation/migration.html  ?
I know it is possible for SQL Server or Oracle, but I'm not sure for MySQL

Comment: Unfortunately this link is now broken.